# PuLP simple problem coming as "Not Solved" when using lpSum

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have the following program, that is coming as Not Solved using PuLP:

```
prob = LpProblem("Risk Decision",LpMaximize)

x = np.arange(3)
n = len(x)

a = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('a', x, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Continuous')
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])

prob += lpSum([a[i]*b[i] for i in range(n)]), "Expected Utility"
```

I removed the constraints to simplify the problem, so the idea is to maximize the function
 **a0 * b0 + a1 * b1 + a2 * b2** 
and since the variables have an upbound of 1 the solution should be (a0=1, a1=1, a2=1), however it is not finding one.

When I try solving it:

```
prob.writeLP("Risk_Decision.lp")
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
```

it comes as Not Solved.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you do `prob.solve()`?

Comment: @loannis that was it, thanks for the quick reply